# How do I change textcolor with a button in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, textcolor

I want to change a certain part of text, named "box" in html to a different color when a button "btn" is clicked with javascript.

But I get the error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'style')".

Here's what I did in js:

```js
const btn = document.getElementById('btn');
const box = document.getElementById('box');

btn.addEventListener('click', function onClick(event) {
  document.box.style.color = 'black';
});
```

I checked different websites and for other instances, this code seems to work. Can anyone tell me where I went wrong? Thanks!

Comment: `document.box` why do you have `document`? remove it.

Comment: Make sure to add ending curly brackets and parenthesis as well

Comment: Don't I have to define the "btn" and "box"-parts via document.? If I delete this, it tells me "Uncaught ReferenceError: getElementById is not defined". Isn't the "document" the html part?

Comment: No you need it for `getElementById`, you do not use it for the variable `box` you defined, just like how you did not use it when you added the event to `btn`

Answer (score 2):

correct the fourth line of your code to

```
box.style.color = 'black';
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const btn = document.getElementById('btn');
const box = document.getElementById('box');

btn.addEventListener('click', function onClick(event) {
  box.style.color = 'blue';
});
```

```html
<button id = "btn">Click Me</button>
<p><span id = "box">Some text.</span> Some more text.</p>
```

You don't need to put `document`. You only put the `element/variable.style.property = "value"` Document is a element of the file: `<html>` and you also can only put 1 element before the style.

Comment: Thanks. You are right. Now the error message is gone but the color still doesn't change when I click the button ... Seems like I made a mistake somewhere else too -.-

Comment: Check for syntax and other stuff

Answer (score 0):

You've got a small mistake. I have adjusted it.

1. You already fetch the box in a variable (box)
2. you can pass to the eventListener an anonymous function

```js
const btn = document.getElementById('btn');
const box = document.getElementById('box');

btn.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
   box.style.color = 'red';
});
```

```html
<div id="box">123</div>
<button id="btn">Change</button>
```

Comment: What are the "bunch of things mixed up"?

Comment: @epascarello Ok. I have dramatised ;-) Two small things: Assign two eventListeners for the same event. Unnecessary attempt to address box, because box was already caught in a variable before.

Comment: unsure where you are getting two event listeners unless you are confusing the function as another event listener. It is valid to do it that way, just a bit weird.

Comment: @epascarello Exactly strange is the word. I concluded that the colleague has implemented an onlclick="onClick()" in his trigger tag. I have then exaggerated my first statement. Actually only a small thing. I had already updated it. Thanks for your questioning. Cheers

Comment: Maybe I made a mistake in the html part as well. I wrote: <h3>Sun colors</h3>
 <span id="box">
  <ul class="second">
  <li class="red"> red</li>
  <li class="orange"> orange</li>
  <li class="yellow"> yellow</li>
  </ul>
 </span>
  <li class="brown"> brown</li>
  <li class="grey"> grey</li>
</ol>
<span> other color lists </span>
 <button id="btn">change sun colors to black</button> 
<script src="index.js"></script>

Answer (score 0):

The issue was the last line of your sample code shouldn't have document at the beginning. It's also missing the closing curly brace and semi-colon but I'm assuming that's further down in your code and you only gave a snippet.

Other than that I want to suggest you use click delegation on the document body. This way you can have a single click listener which you can then add more checks to

```
document.body.addEventListener('click', e => {
    e.target.id = 'btn' && ( document.getElementById('box').style.color = 'black' );
}, false);
```

In the above code we add a click event listener to the document body (the `<body>` tag in HTML). Then in the listener we check if the target's ID is equal to **btn**, and if this matches we change the element with ID of **box**

If this looks a little weird it's a more succinct way to write the following

```
document.body.addEventListener('click', e => {
    if (e.target.id = 'btn') {
        document.getElementById('box').style.color = 'black';
    }
}, false);
```

You could still set #btn and #box as constants if you like